# How do the bow-related Archery skill perks affect crossbows?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I noticed* that some of the [Archery skill perks](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Archery) are bow-specific or bow-related, based on their descriptions. I would like to know how they affect crossbows.

- Does the 'Quick Shot ' archery perk (*can draw a bow 30% faster*) affect crossbows? Does it make the crossbow reload speed faster?
- What about 'Hunter's Discipline' and 'Power Shot'? They are described as "*recover twice as many arrows from dead bodies*" and "*arrows stagger all but the largest opponents 50% of the time*", respectively - do these perks affect crossbow bolts too?
- These perks don't seem to affect crossbows (based on their description), but do they have any gameplay effect on the crossbows: Ranger (*able to move faster with a drawn bow*) and Steady Hand (*zooming in with a bow slows time by 25%/50%*)?

<sup>* I know. I'm late to the party and just started Dawnguard.</sup>

Comment: Definitely things I'd love to know as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Everything that affects bows affects crossbows as well (damage multiplier, etc.), even "Deadly Aim". Those perks that aren't immediately obvious work like this:

- "Hunter's Discipline" - more bolts (from mobs who drop bolts in the first place)
- "Ranger" - move faster while aiming and reloading
- "Quick Draw" - faster reload

The mechanics of the weapons can be confusing.

- Bow: Ready → draw → aim → shoot → ready.
- Crossbow: Ready → aim → shoot → reload → ready.

Quick draw yields faster draw for bows and faster reload for crossbows. Ranger lets you move faster while aiming with your bow or crossbow. The thing with a crossbow is that you aim an already loaded weapon, and with the bow, the draw action is part of the aiming. In the end, there's no real difference.

Comment: RE: the Ranger and Eagle Eye perks. Crossbows aren't aimed similar to bows (which is done by holding right-click on the PC). Right-clicking a crossbow does a melee attack.

Comment: I have both bow and crossbow and aiming and melee attacks are executed the exact same way.

Comment: I made a mistake on my comment above: it's hold 'left-click', not 'right-click'. And it should be 'drawn', not 'aimed'. On the PC, the player character will only draw the bow once you hold left-click. Holding left-click on the crossbow will not draw the crossbow. AFAIK, the crossbow is not drawn by the player character due to the nature of the weapon. (Once the character has 'loaded' the crossbow, it is effectively already and always drawn, unlike the bow which has to be manually drawn.) Hunter's Discipline is described as allowing you to be "able to move faster with a *drawn* bow."

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: D'oh! Another correction on my comment above: *Ranger\** is described as allowing you to be "able to move faster with a *drawn* bow".

Comment: Yea, drawn bow is the same as aimed crossbow.